# Low quality icon in taskbar of a Stage. JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

Why Stage icon so low quality? The original image is much better.
How to fix it?

I used this code to setting image as stage icon:

```
stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/res/app_icon.png"));
```

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

Original icon:
[image: Original icon]

Comment: Scale the icon down to meet the OS requirements before hand

Comment: Sorry, but I have not quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Your icon is 300x300, the task bar icon is may 32x32.  You create a version of your icon at 32x32 so it looks the way you want it to and isn't scaled either by JavaFX or OS through a mechanism you don't know and can't control

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update**

Unfortunately the implementation of the icon chooser in JavaFX 8 does not always choose the best icon size for the application from the list of available icons.

See:

- [JDK-8091186 Windows 7 taskbar icon is blurry](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091186).
- [JDK-8087459 Ugly icon in Windows task bar](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087459).

The issues are (currently) scheduled to be addressed in Java 9.

Some comments on those issues are:

> Indeed, Glass currently supports assigning only one icon for a window, it won't allow one to assign a set of differently sized icons. This feature needs to be implemented in Glass.

--

> I have noticed that when setting multiple icons, only the last one in the list returned by getIcons() is used. It doesn't matter if other icons, with better resolutions are in the list.

If you provide a list of icons of different sizes, try putting the size you expect to be used most last in the list (perhaps order the list from smallest to largest or place a 48x48 icon, which is the size used in the quick launch area on Windows 7, as the last or only element in the list).  Unfortunately, I do not have access to a Windows machine to test the best icon size for that platform.

---

Icon Guidelines (but be aware of the information in the update above):

- Provide a set of high quality icons of different sizes to the list
  returned from
  [`stage.getIcons()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/Stage.html#getIcons--).
- The best fit size will be chosen by the runtime.
- Use standard icon
  sizes which most operating systems can work with without further scaling (for
  instance item size is a power of two or 48x48).
- Use high quality source images (the original source image in your question seems a bit blurry to me).
- For very small icons, sometimes a pure scale of a larger icon to a smaller size is not best.  Sometimes it is best for the icon designer to clean up and remove intricate details from the small icon, which might be OK in a larger icon - see the [discussion on icon size on Pushing Pixels](http://www.pushing-pixels.org/2011/11/04/about-those-vector-icons.html) to help understand why.
- Info on what icon sizes are used by what OSes is in [this icon handbook](http://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/windows/).

---

```
stage.getIcons().addAll(
    new Image("/res/app_icon64x64.png"),
    new Image("/res/app_icon32x32.png"),
    new Image("/res/app_icon16x16.png")
);
```

---

A great source of high quality icons in a variety of sizes is http://www.iconarchive.com, for example [this refresh icon](http://www.iconarchive.com/show/flatastic-8-icons-by-custom-icon-design/Refresh-icon.html).

Comment: I did just as you said, but it did not help.
I think the problem is not in the big picture, but in the JavaFX.

I created 256x256 => 32x32 images and
when zooming interface in Windows image becomes blurred.

[100%](http://cdn.img42.com/33a6f1d0777b0504411be168489d3467.png)
[200%](http://cdn.img42.com/1b0f170427280921d9d2be29b2e1911d.png)
[300%](http://cdn.img42.com/a13cc4782d73199876f7891f40e622be.png)

Comment: Yes, see the updated answer: There are deficiencies in the JavaFX 8 implementation on Windows 7 in regards to choosing the best icon - try placing only a 48x48 icon in the stage icon list (or as the last element in the stage icon list).

Comment: in windows they wont stay when I click right "pin to taskbar" is that the default behaviour? and how to fix it?

Comment: Martin, that is a different question.  Please ask as a new question.

Comment: New URLs for the linked issues: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091186 https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8087459

Comment: Thx Natix, I edited the answer to point to the new issue tracker URLs.

Comment: With FX 17 an Windows 11 the icon shows only top left in app window, but not in taskbar. I tried with 16, 32, 36, 48, 57, 60, 64, 70, 72, 76, 96, 114, 120, 128, 144, 150, 152, 180, 192, 256 and 310 pixels. Any idea what to do?

Comment: @horvoje Yes, setting the icon on the stage in the app no longer shows that icon in the taskbar for recent JavaFX and Windows versions.  To get your icon to show, you need to create an installer (use jpackage and set the icon via command line switch to the jpackage tool) and install the app.  Unfortunately, it is not completely simple to do.